# How to connect to website's DB from xampp

Tags: php, mysql, database, amazon-web-services, xampp

I have a project in htdocs and i have a file connect.php 
I'm trying to connect to our website's database because i will be inserting stuff in there but i can't connect to the db somehow.

```
$servername = "http://websitename.com";
$username = "root";
$password = "websitepassword";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=coverview", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }



    $resulttwo = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tablename;");
$resulttwo->execute();

while ($rowtwo = $resulttwo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    echo $rowtwo['fieldname'];
}
```

somehow it is not connecting. this is the result.

```
Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\play2winsychronizer\connect.php on line 15
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. 
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\play2winsychronizer\connect.php on line 27

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\play2winsychronizer\connect.php on line 27
```

when i use our website's public IP for the host instead of "http://website.com/"

this part of the error disappears:

> Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known. in C:\xampp\htdocs\play2winsychronizer\connect.php on line 15

**NOTE:** I am in xampp and if i use localhost, i will be connected to my local database which i don't want. i want to connect to a website's database.

Comment: Are you sure that `$servername = "http://websitename.com";` is a proper server name? This means that if you site is on `websitename.com` it doesn't mean that database will be available on this address too.

Comment: Try replacing `$servername = "http://websitename.com;"` with `$servername = "127.0.0.1"`

Comment: @u_mulder well the database is in http://websitename.com/phpmyadmin
does that mean the db is in http://websitename.com ???

I also tried using the website's public ip and part of the error disappeared.

I edited my question above to show which part of the error is gone.

Comment: I added the missing quote in your `$servername = "http://websitename.com;` it was throwing off syntax highlighting. Am pretty sure that `$servername = "http://websitename.com";` is what you meant.

Comment: @RiggsFolly This will only connect me to my local database. The project i am working on will stay here in xampp and will not be uploaded to the website. I am trying to connect from my local server to the website's db.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to whitelist you local public ip address on your server. If you have cPanel there is a like for it. By default most servers are only configured to accept connections from localhost.

Comment: We're using Amazon Aws. Do you know where i could whitelist my local IP there? :o

Comment: peep dis: http://mariolurig.com/coding/connect-remotely-mysql-database-amazon-ec2-server/

Comment: I did what it said.. only on the last part.
instead of /etc/init.d/mysql restart

I used 

 sudo service apache2 restart
 sudo service mysql restart

because /etc/init.d/mysql restart says i have no permission to..
I also rebooted the instance.

I am still getting the same error :c

Comment: I also tried sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
it worked. But i am still getting the error when i try to connect.

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mysql restart` is the same thing as `mysql restart`, just with the explicit path. Using `service` takes care of mysqld daemon (process). As opposed to mysql binary. But the truth is, if you don't have access to mess with mysql, then you're probably on a shared server and won't have access to set up a remote connection. You may just need to speak to Amazon tech support and have them do it.

Comment: Most hosts will gladly take care of this for you anyway. Just need to give them your local IP.

Comment: You have to pay aws for support though :C

Comment: I accidentally closed my browser's tab and opened my project again localhost/projectname/connect.php

and it is already working now :o
I guess what i did worked. Maybe the error was cached o3o

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear! Sometimes it just takes a minute.